# Transit visa through Sydney from Fiji to Abu Dhabi having Lebanese citizenship

Tags: transit-visas, australia, lebanese-citizens

I am Lebanese and want to travel from Fiji to Lebanon having to transit by Sydney airport.
I will have to stay at the airport 8 hours. My question is do I need to apply for a transit visa ?

Comment: Please be aware that if for any reason you are required to stay longer than 8 hours (that is the limit) you will be subject to quarantine and will have to leave the airport (it is not 24/7).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa

Lebanese citizens are not eligible to transit without a visa.